# Writing in a tabular format to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have two lists which I am trying to write to a csv file in a specific format.
Lets call these lists `colHead` and `rowVals`.
The list `colHead` contains names of the column headers which need to be written to a csv file. I have achieved this using the following code:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(colHead)
```

Now, `rowVals` is a list which contains 250 values. These 250 values, are arranged in an orderly format. I wish to write every 25 values from `rowVals` under each `colHead` to achieve the results.

The code I am using (it is not giving me the desired results) is:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(colHead)
    for i in range(0,25):
        writer.writerow(rowVal) 
        i+=25
```

Finally I want to write this format to the csv format.

```
colHead1,colHead2,colHead3......colHead10
rowVal1, rowVal26, .            , .
rowval2, rowVal27, .            , .
.       , .      , .            , .
.       , .      , .            , .
rowVal25, .      , .            , rowVal250
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong as well.

Comment: Your code lappears to write the same `subpageurl` value 25 times. Please [edit] your question and show the actual contents of the two lists (or at least a portion of each one).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have made the required changes.

Comment: Your change still writes the same thing 25 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just feed `writerows` with a generator comprehension slicing your 250-item list with a step of 25 like this, 25 times:

```
writer.writerows(rowVal[i::25] for i in range(25))
```

I get:

```
rowval1,rowval26,rowval51,rowval76,rowval101,rowval126,rowval151,rowval176,rowval201,rowval226
rowval2,rowval27,rowval52,rowval77,rowval102,rowval127,rowval152,rowval177,rowval202,rowval227
rowval3,rowval28,rowval53,rowval78,rowval103,rowval128,rowval153,rowval178,rowval203,rowval228
...
rowval24,rowval49,rowval74,rowval99,rowval124,rowval149,rowval174,rowval199,rowval224,rowval249
rowval25,rowval50,rowval75,rowval100,rowval125,rowval150,rowval175,rowval200,rowval225,rowval250
```

Comment: simple, elegant, and effective.

Comment: Thank you for your compact answer.